# How to fetch payment details using Razorpay PHP API?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, razorpay

I am trying to integrate the code for fetching payment details.

> billno: This value will be taken from the URL.

My current code:

```
include 'razorpay/Razorpay.php';
use Razorpay\Api\Api;

$api = new Api('Secret ID', 'Secret Key');

$payment = $api->payment->fetch($_REQUEST['billno']);
$text =  json_encode($payment->toArray());
$obj = json_decode($text);
$shopping_id = $obj->{'notes'}->{'shopping_id'};

$rzp_amount = $obj->{'amount'};//xheck
$real_amount = $rzp_amount/100;
$rzp_key = $obj->{'id'};
$rzp_status = $obj->{'status'}; //Authorised cgecj
$rzp_descp = $obj->{'description'};
$rzp_mail = $obj->{'email'};
$rzp_phone = $obj->{'contact'};
$rzp_address = $obj->{'notes'}->{'address'};
$rzp_timestamp = $obj->{'created_at'};
$rzp_method = $obj->{'method'};
```

Extracting the billno using the code would give us the above mentioned $rzp variables.

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing? Can you provide a sample value for billno?

Comment: exactly same problem facing. Not able to get whole JSON response (individual values are accessible but not JSON object).  and also instead of error JSON  it gives **fatal error** for invalid credentials passing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `payment->fetch` call returns a Payment Entity, and has all the data members available for direct access. You don't have to decode JSON yourselves, that is taken care of by the SDK:

```
include 'razorpay/Razorpay.php';
use Razorpay\Api\Api;

$api = new Api('Secret ID', 'Secret Key');

$payment = $api->payment->fetch($_REQUEST['billno']);

echo $payment->amount;
print_r($payment->notes);
```

*Disclaimer*: I work for Razorpay

Comment: Hi @Nemo, From where can i get the information of the user who has made payment in payment.captured event?

Comment: Please take a look at the entire Payment entity definition [here](https://docs.razorpay.com/docs/return-objects#payment-entity). Look at the contact, and email fields.

Comment: Hi Thanks. But thats not waht I was looking at. This was the one i was looking at. https://razorpay.com/docs/virtual-accounts/api/

Comment: @ShashankHegde Can you write a mail to integrations@razorpay.com regarding this? This doesn't look related to the original question.

Comment: Hi @Nemo How do I check if the payment has been captured?

As of now after paying successfully through netbanking in test mode, I see captured as false.

Comment: Please check this issue and give some solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374107/wordpress-razorpay-quick-payments-plugin-how-to-change-amount-for-payment-from

Comment: Can you please tell me , how to fetch bank details  ?